# What should I do if the OP edits their question and significantly changes the meaning?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I found [an edit by a question poster](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19229677) that seems problematic.

- Different questions should be asked in different questions. Editing a question to significantly changes its meaning is bad.

  In this case, the original question asks about nested initializer list, while the edited part asks about classes (constructor, destructor, polymorphism). That's definitely "significantly changes its meaning".
- Sometimes high reputation users rollback edits if the OP does that.

  I can't find example this time, but I'm sure that it happened. I will add an example if I come across one <sub>and still remember to add an example</sub>.
- I wrote "Rollback to revision 1" in the edit comment. So, that should not "deviates from the original intent of the post".
- The only answer's last significant edit was several hours before the edit part was added, and therefore completely unrelated to the edit.

However, my edit was still rejected. What should I do in that case? Should I make such edits?

Comment: "Editing a question to significantly changes its meaning is bad." [citation needed]

Comment: Why would you want to rollback a change made 5 years ago?

Comment: *I wrote "Rollback to revision 1" in the edit comment.* I think there might be a bit of confusion on this point. Normally when you see this comment on edits it's because the user went into the edit history and used the rollback link to make the site revert the post to a previous version. That's a comment created by the system when that happens.

Comment: The key detail is that nobody found it necessary to rollback the edit for the past 5 years.  It got 10 more helpful votes in its present state.  Getting it approved now is very unlikely.

Comment: [Someone was confused with the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482584/pass-array-values-to-constructor#comment85971832_49482584). Of course an edit should not be used to "answer the question".

Comment: If someone was confused why not ask for an explenation instead of reverting that edit? I understand that the edit wasn't the best but this seems a bit drastic considering the question (5 years old, 14 upvotes, 5k+ views)

Comment: @BSMP I think that users without instant edit privilege don't have (or have hidden) rollback link.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to hide the rollback option for users under 2K since you still have to have your edits reviewed.

Comment: @AndréKool I guess most people just skip the edit part, consider that it is not answered at all and is unrelated to the issue.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Not really, the answer to the other question is "yes, it should be rolled back", the answer to this question is "you should have a more clear revision comment or moderator flag". Different answer, different question. Also in my case I don't have edit without review privilege, just suggesting edits.

Answer (score 8):

You should just flag for moderator attention, rather than trying to make such an edit through the suggested edit system.

That said, your revision comment wasn't very good.  You said *that* you were rolling back the post, but not *why that was appropriate*.  If you wanted to roll the dice and try to get such an edit through review then at the very least you'd have needed to say something like, "Rolling back multiple additional new questions that were edited in.  New questions should be asked as new questions, not edited into an existing question." This is made trickier by the fact that you need that revision comment to not only explain to the reviewers why the edit is appropriate, but to the post author.

Comment: Would moderator attention in this case overkill? (they can be very busy)

Comment: @user202729 Authors have such a high frequency of rolling back edits like these that it actually ends up being necessary in a pretty high percentage of cases anyway.

Comment: @user202729 The author of the post.  Which other author is there?